# ListDensityPlot and DensityPlot do not give the same results?

Tags: plotting

I am plotting the same function using `ListDensityPlot` and `DensityPlot` but the output is different!
There are some points where the function is complex or pure imaginary where `DensityPlot`show this region as White. However, `ListDensityPlot` show coloring in the same region.

```
mod = ParallelTable[
   With[{κ = 0.23}, {ky, ϵ, 
     Sqrt[-ky^2 + ϵ^2 + κ^2 - 
      Sqrt[ϵ^2 - 4 ky^2 κ^2 + 
       4 ϵ^2 κ^2]]}], {ky, -0.35, 0.35, 
    0.001}, {ϵ, 0, 0.2, 0.001}];
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[mod, 1]]
```

[image]

```
With[{κ = 0.23}, 
 DensityPlot[
  Sqrt[-ky^2 + ϵ^2 + κ^2 - 
   Sqrt[ϵ^2 - 4 ky^2 κ^2 + 
    4 ϵ^2 κ^2]], {ky, -0.35, 0.35}, {ϵ, 
   0, .2}, PlotRange -> Full, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your function has complex values outside the region shown in the `DensityPlot`.  In particular, in the blue region in the first plot, the values of the function are actually complex. I don't know why `ListDensityPlot` is plotting anything in that region.

Comment: @march Exactly, that is strange!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot) discards all of the complex valued entries, and then interpolates the remaining data. One possible workaround is to replace all the complex valued entries with some number, and then adjust the plot range so that the number is out of range. For instance:

```
With[{trunc = Replace[Flatten[mod, 1], _Complex -> -20., {2}]},
    ListDensityPlot[trunc, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, may you please explain the choose of -20?

Comment: @HD2006 It was just some number outside the range from 0 to 1, and a number less than 0 avoided changing the coloring.